# Extract year from complicated title in R

Tags: r, formatting, text-extraction

I have a data frame in R where I have couple of variables, right now concerned is with two variables, title and Date. I write down the short data similar with real data frame

```
   Title                                    Date
   Veterans, Sacrame                        1997
   Action Newsmaker                         2005
   New Tri-Cable                            1990 mar
   EFEST June 16, 1987                      28494
   The Inhuman Perception: what we do       1999 june
   New Tri-Cable                            2003 july/august
   Interviews Concerning His/her            1991-1992
   Festival EFEST June 6, 1997              83443
   Intervention of the people               Undated
```

What I want is  create a new variable year where we only have the year(no date/month or anything like that).
I can extract year from date format or exact similar text format, but here it's different because the title is complicated and not same(not equal word/letter) for each row. I am just wondering any easy way to create a variable 'year' in r-studio I desire. I can extract the year from the date variable if it's some sort of date format. However in some data where the date are like 83443, but I see the year in title  but can't extract the year manually because of huge dataset of this format.

Comment: Also please include the exact output you expect from this block of text.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's edited now.

Comment: For this specific case, try `do.call(paste0, data.frame(gsub(".*\\b(\\d{4})\\b.*|.+", '\\1', as.matrix(df))))`

Comment: `df$Year <- as.integer(sub('.*?\\b(\\d{4})\\b.*', '\\1', paste(df$Title, df$Date)))`

Answer (score 0):

Use mdy to convert to Date class and then year to extract the year.

```
library(lubridate)

year(mdy(dat1$Title, quiet = TRUE))
## [1]   NA   NA   NA 1987   NA   NA   NA 1997   NA
```

### Note

The data in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "Title                                    Date
Veterans, Sacrame                        1997
Action Newsmaker                         2005
New Tri-Cable                            1990 mar
EFEST June 16, 1987                      28494
The Inhuman Perception: what we do       1999 june
New Tri-Cable                            2003 july/august
Interviews Concerning His/her            1991-1992
Festival EFEST June 6, 1997              83443
Intervention of the people               Undated"
L <- readLines(textConnection(Lines))
dat1 <- read.csv(text = sub("   +", ";", trimws(L)), sep = ";")
```